# Insert Select ALTHOUGH some records from the select are with errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Is very simple to explain what i want to do but I think is a little bit difficult to implment, well... the think is that Im doing a stored procedure that recives an XML param, then Im doing an insert select with the records in the XML, somethin like this:

```
insert into @pedXMl
SELECT distinct
    LTRIM(RTRIM(nref.value('@COL_0','VARCHAR(50)'))) NumPedido,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(nref.value('@COL_1','VARCHAR(50)'))) CodAlmacen
    FROM @PI_ParamXML.nodes('/CARGAPEDIDO/REGISTRO') as R(nref)
    WHERE LTRIM(nref.value('@COL_0','VARCHAR(50)')) <> ''
```

The thing is that in my xml comming like parameter will be records with error, what I want is to keep inserting ALTHOUGH a record throws error.
Sorry my bad English Im traying the best, I hope you were underdstood and can help with this! thanks!

Comment: Hi, is this still open? Do you need further help? If this issue is solved, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check below the best answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on *What is an error?*

This might be

- invalid XML (only if you pass in the XML as string and cast it internally)
- invalid internal structue (nodes/attributes missing, bad nestings...)
- wrong values in casts (should be `INT`, but isn't)
- broken business rules (e.g. value cannot be 1 if other value is 0)

Anyway: One Statement is one step. It will work in total or it will fail.

One way to achieve what you want is a *row-by-row* approach (`CURSOR`), the second was a set based approach with a staging table:

As an example I assume it's the wrong value, but the general approach should be quite the same with other problems:

The second Data-node has an invalid `valueInt`

```
DECLARE @passedIn XML=
'<root>
    <data rowID="1">
        <valueInt>111</valueInt>
        <valueString>hello1</valueString>
    </data>
    <data rowID="2">
        <valueInt>222xyz</valueInt>
        <valueString>hello2</valueString>
    </data>
    <data rowID="3">
        <valueInt>333</valueInt>
        <valueString>hello3</valueString>
    </data>
</root>';
```

This is the `CURSOR` approach

```
DECLARE @target TABLE(RowID INT,valueInt INT,valueString NVARCHAR(MAX));
DECLARE @errors TABLE(rowID INT,DataNode XML);

DECLARE @rowID INT;
DECLARE @vInt NVARCHAR(MAX); --type is NVARCHAR!!!
DECLARE @vString NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @DataNode XML;

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
(
    SELECT data.value('@rowID','int') AS RowID
          ,data.value('valueInt[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ValueInt --type is NVARCHAR!!!
          ,data.value('valueString[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ValueString
          ,data.query('.') AS DataNode
    FROM @passedIn.nodes('/root/data') AS A(data)
);
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @rowID,@vInt,@vString,@DataNode;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO @target VALUES(@rowID,@vInt,@vString);
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO @errors VALUES(@rowID,@DataNode);
    END CATCH
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @rowID,@vInt,@vString,@DataNode;
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;

--This is the result
SELECT * FROM @target;
SELECT * FROM @errors;
```

Clean up and re-start with the set-based approach via staging table

```
DELETE FROM @target;
DELETE FROM @errors;

SELECT data.value('@rowID','int') AS RowID
      ,data.value('valueInt[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ValueInt --type is NVARCHAR!!!
      ,data.value('valueString[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ValueString
      ,data.query('.') AS DataNode
INTO #stagingTable
FROM @passedIn.nodes('/root/data') AS A(data);

INSERT INTO @target
SELECT RowID,ValueInt,ValueString 
FROM #stagingTable
WHERE ISNUMERIC(ValueInt)=1;

INSERT INTO @errors
SELECT RowID,DataNode 
FROM #stagingTable
WHERE ISNUMERIC(ValueInt)=0;

SELECT * FROM @target;
SELECT * FROM @errors;

GO
DROP TABLE #stagingTable;
```

Comment: I´ve considered to do this but, I got so many records and I think this could affect the performance, isn´t it?

Comment: @C.Lopez Yes, without any doubts... If you cannot be sure about your data's quality you must invest extra effort. `CAST`s to other types are expensive. If you have to retrieve your data as strings to first check them before you cast them you have to do this twice... You did not explain which kind of errors you expect. Neither did you mention the version of your SQL Server.  Starting with SS2012 you might read about [`TRY_CAST`, `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_PARSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)